# Neither pyautogui nor pydirectinput works when I try the click function

Tags: python, click, pyautogui

I'm trying to use the click function. Even though the cursor moves to the exact coordinates, it doesn't click, and the process finishes with code 0

```
import tkinter as tk
import pydirectinput as p
import time

coords = [0, 0]
p.FAILSAFE = False

def white_screen():
    overlay = tk.Tk()

    def close(event):
        coords[0] = event.x
        coords[1] = event.y
        overlay.quit()

    overlay.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    overlay.attributes("-alpha", 0.3)
    overlay.configure(bg='white')
    overlay.bind("<Button-1>", close)
    overlay.mainloop()

white_screen()

time.sleep(1)
p.click(x=coords[0], y=coords[1],clicks = 2)
```

I used pyautogui first, and then I saw someone recommend pydirectinput, but that didn't work either.
i also tried running the code as admin.

Comment: I get the `overlay` staying on top, so the click seems to click on the tk window. If I change the quit to: `overlay.destroy()`, now the overlay goes away and the click operates on the window underneath.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Using overlay.destroy() instead of overlay.quit() fixed the problem for me, as someone mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the `mouse` library in a simple and practical way:

```
import mouse

# Replace 'x' and 'y' with the desired coordinates in pixel
x = 100
y = 200

mouse.move(x, y)
mouse.click("left")
```